# Is Frobenius norm induced up to a scalar factor?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I know that the Frobenius norm is not induced since $||I||_F=\sqrt n\neq 1$.

But what if we consider the norm $\frac 1 {\sqrt n} ||\cdot ||_F$?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a good question, because all the time we proof that a norm is induced, that the identity matrix has 1 norm.
But first of all it is a norm? And if it is, what you think by which vector norm induced it? And my last question is: why do you need that?
By my intuition I may say it is not an induced norm, because with this method we could make induced norms easly by scaling. But I'm also waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any induced norm satisfies $\|A\|\ge \rho(A)$, where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$, *i.e.* the largest absolute value of its eigenvalues. This fact is stated without proof [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Matrix_norm&oldid=622243996#Induced_norm); here is a proof.

> Any induced norm is of the form
>   $$\|A\|=\max_x\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}.$$ Let $x^*$ be an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda^*$ with the largest absolute value. Then $$\|A\|\ge\frac{\|Ax^*\|}{\|x^*\|}=\frac{\|\lambda^*x^*\|}{\|x^*\|}=|\lambda^*|\frac{\|x^*\|}{\|x^*\|}=|\lambda^*|.$$

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then your norm is $\|A\|=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\|A\|_F=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$
while $\rho(A)=1$, contradicting the above inequality.

Comment: Can you also prove the first sentence? It could be trivial, but there are conditions like: in an induced norm the idenity matrix has $1$ norm, or $\|A\| \geq \rho(A)$, but I've never seen the proof for this statments. Could you edit your answer please?

Comment: @user153012: Edited. You can also prove that the induced norm of an identity matrix is $1$ in a similar way, simply by plugging in the definition.

Comment: So the norm above by @giulio is also not induced. Thank you Rahul. Nice answer!

Comment: I think I will give you the offered reputation, because I wanted this part of the proof, but @Rahul
am I wrong with the following reasoning? By staying at your example, let $$A = B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Since $A$ and $B$ are the same projector $AB=A=B$ so $\|AB\| = (1/ \sqrt{2}) \|AB\|_F = 1/ \sqrt{2}$. On the other hand $\|A\| \cdot \|B\| = (1/ \sqrt{2}) \|A\|_F \cdot (1/ \sqrt{2}) \|B\|_F = 1/2$. And because $1/ \sqrt{2} > 1/2$ it violates the $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \cdot \|B\|$ submultiplicativ property of matrix norm. So the above defined function is not a matrix norm.

Comment: @user153012: Sure, your argument shows that the proposed norm is not submultiplicative, so it cannot be an induced norm. However if you want to argue that it is also not a matrix norm at all, you should be aware that not all authors require matrix norms to be submultiplicative.

Comment: Yes @Rahul, I know it. :) But I always mention submultiplicative matrix norms, because if you don't require this property, then the matrix norm is nothing else just a vector norm on matrices. One last thing, you said since it is not submultiplicative it is not induced, but it is always true? So the definition of an induced norm is just understood on submultiplicative matrix norms? Or something like that?

Comment: I didn't expect this answer to turn into "Please prove as many properties of induced norms as possible", but here you go: From the definition of induced norm, one can prove submultiplicativity as follows: $\|AB\| = \max\dfrac{\|ABx\|}{\|x\|} \le \max\dfrac{\|A\|\|Bx\|}{\|x\|} = \|A\|\max\dfrac{\|Bx\|}{\|x\|} = \|A\|\|B\|$. First equality is the definition of $\|AB\|$, inequality is because $\|A\|\ge\dfrac{\|Ay\|}{\|y\|}$ for all $y$ and so $\|Ay\|\le\|A\|\|y\|$, last equality follows from the definition of $\|B\|$.

Comment: That was also nice. Thank you very much, and sorry for that, I didn't wanted to waste your time.